# Fasting and retrograde ejaculation

Tags: masturbation

Assyalm Aleukim I have a question about fasting we all know that masterbauting with ejaculation breaks your fast but what about retrograde ejaculation it's when you reached climax and felt as if you ejaculated but nothing came out because you pressed so hard on your private part nothing came out does that break your fast and if it does and I didn't know will my fast still be accepted?